# standard function to translate iso-639 codes to language name?

Tags: php, linux, internationalization, iso

I guess there should be some standard method for this, just to avoid everybody retyping dull constants for their applications. ;)
I am looking for a function (usable in a php web app on linux) that can take two ISO639 language codes and returns the name of the *first* language in the *second* language, i.e.
`foo("fr","de")` should return `"französisch"` and `foo("de","fr")` should return `"allemagne"`.

Is there?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Locale::getDisplayLanguage](http://www.php.net/manual/en/locale.getdisplaylanguage.php) is what you need. It is in PHP International Extension so if it is not on you have to turn on php_intl.so (or dll if Windows).

```
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0', '<')) {
    exit ('php_intl extension is available on PHP 5.3.0 or later.');
}    
if (!class_exists('Locale')) {
    exit ('You need to install php_intl extension.');
}

echo Locale::getDisplayLanguage('fr', 'de');
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot @akky

Comment: I wrote an answer for the opposite direction, [display name to iso code conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25041306/converting-language-name-to-locale-code/57989232)  as well.